# jest does not recognize TypeError thrown by URL constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, typeerror, ts-jest

Jest `.toThrow(TypeError)` does not match TypeError thrown by `new URL` constructor.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
Jest version is `29.4.2`

Test case:

```js
it("throws TypeError when url is invalid", () => {
  expect(() => {
    new URL(""); // This does not work
    // throw new TypeError(); // This works
  }).toThrow(TypeError);
})
```

Output is:

```
Expected constructor: TypeError
Received constructor: TypeError

Received message: "Invalid URL: "

      13 |     it("throws TypeError when url is invalid", () => {
      14 |         expect(() => {
    > 15 |             new URL("");
         |             ^
      16 |             // throw new TypeError();
      17 |         }).toThrow(TypeError);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's a long standing bug in Node.js/Jest, and it's related to:

- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10045
- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2549
- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/31852
- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/46558

On my machine using `Node.js v16.19.0` and `Jest v29.4.3` I got:

```
    expect(received).toThrow(expected)

    Expected constructor: TypeError
    Received constructor: TypeError

    Received message: "Invalid URL"
```

Even if you run

```
try {
  new URL("");
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error instanceof TypeError);
}
```

With node you'll get `true` but if you add this to your tests and run them with Jest you'll have `false`.

Which shows that the Error objects are not identical.

---

For now, I believe that you can create your custom error and throw it when URLs are invalid, then you can use that error type in your tests