# jest: toBeInstanceOf(Object) fails

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, javascript-objects

Just checking that we're exporting an object is failing as follows:

```js
import * as Foo from './foo';

describe('Foo', () => {
  test('should export an object', () => {
    expect(Foo).toBeInstanceOf(Object);
  });
});
```

getting this error:

[image: expect(received).toBeInstanceOf(expected)]

While I can workaround using `typeof`:

```
import * as Foo from './foo';

describe('Foo', () => {
  test('should export an object', () => {
-    expect(Foo).toBeInstanceOf(Object);
+    expect(typeof LivingAppsCoreReact).toEqual('object');
  });
});
```

I'd like to understand **why** Jest defines that `Object` constructor isn't... `Object` constructor.

Checked that the object is exporting the actual keys ✅

---

Env:

```bash
$» npm ls jest                                                            1 ↵
my-project@0.31.5
├── jest@29.3.1
└─┬ ts-jest@29.0.3
  └── jest@29.3.1 deduped
```

Comment: Note that a *lot* of things are objects in JS. `null` is one in `typeof`, `[]` is one for both `typeof` and `instanceof`, etc. That means this test isn't asserting a lot. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8511350/3072442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bug on Jest/Node side, as the globals on Jest environment differ from Node's, see:

- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2549
- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/31852
- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/46558

When you use a default export, the type of your exported element is [`Object`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#moduleexports), and then when you compare it to "Jest's Object type" that fails the test as they're in different contexts.

This is also related to behaviors like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75524385/5078746

---

In your case, you can use destructuring in case you are using named exports (e.g `export const Foo = {...}`) which will lead Jest to evaluate your objects in the same context.

I mean move from

```
import * as Foo from './foo';
```

To

```
import { Foo } from './foo';
```

Or, you can check for object properties with [`.toMatchObject(object)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tomatchobjectobject) instead of checking if the Object is an Object.

Answer (score 0):

**Jest globals differ from Node globals**

That's one of the longest arguments between **Jest** and **Node**. There is a difference between the Jest globals and the Node globals - you can find more information on this github's open issue [Jest globals differ from Node globals](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2549).

In other words, the toBeInstanceOf function works for object instances of classes that you create. However, it won't work correctly for an instance of the global Array class. I would consider using the toBeInstanceOf function for asserting against your example above. Please have a look at the [toBeInstanceOf](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tomatchobjectobject) docs and the example code below.

*That's from the docs*

```
describe('toMatchObject applied to arrays', () => {
  test('the number of elements must match exactly', () => {
    expect([{foo: 'bar'}, {baz: 1}]).toMatchObject([{foo: 'bar'}, {baz: 1}]);
  });

  test('.toMatchObject is called for each elements, so extra object properties are okay', () => {
    expect([{foo: 'bar'}, {baz: 1, extra: 'quux'}]).toMatchObject([
      {foo: 'bar'},
      {baz: 1},
    ]);
  });
});
```